# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working with an Android project I've Imported from someone else. I've got all the dependencies sorted, there are no errors in the project, but when I try and launch it, I get:

```
04-08 16:49:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 16:49:41.761: E/AndroidRuntime(19254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
      instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.me.app/com.me.app.ui.ActivityDashboard}: 
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
      "com.me.app.ui.ActivityDashboard" 
      on path: /data/app/com.me.app-1.apk
```

My Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ActivityDashboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

This seems to be a common problem, I've read all the other questions I've found and done the following, all to no avail:

- ADT and the SDK are fully updated
- I'm building against Android 2.3.3 (SDK 10)
- This is selected under Android Build Target, and the Library is in the Java Build Path
- All the classpaths in the Manifest are correct, I've double checked them all.
- All Activities are in the Manifest, with the correct Intents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and the Library is in the Java Build Path

That is incorrect. Please back out this change, then move the JAR into your project's `libs/` directory.

While adding a JAR manually to your build path will satisfy the compiler at compile time, it will not add the contents of the JAR to the APK file at runtime, resulting in `ClassNotFoundException`s and the like.

Note that I am referring to third-party JARs, such as [the first four entries in your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yup2.png). None of those appear to be in `libs/`, and all need to be.

The sole exceptions for the all-JARs-must-be-in-`libs/` rule are:

1. Android's own platform JAR, attached to your project via selecting the build target (reason: this JAR's contents specifically does not need to be included in your APK)
2. Android library projects, which have their own `libs/` directories for any third-party JARs that they reference

Your core error is that `com.me.app.ui.ActivityDashboard` is not found, suggesting that this is from one of your four JARs that are not in `libs/`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Library entry was added by right clicking the project > "Android Tools" > "Fix Project Properties". Sigh.

Comment: So I removed the library from the Java Build Path, which broke all of my imports. I then moved `android.jar` to `/libs`, and re-added it (the import errors didn't go away until I re-added). Now I get a console message saying `Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.`

Comment: @TomMedley: Your third-party JAR for some reason contains classes in the `java.*` or `javax.*` packages. That is not advisable. Are you sure that this third-party JAR is designed for use on Android?

Comment: this is the `jar` included in the Android SDK. It is not a third-party `jar`.

Comment: @TomMedley: "Are you saying that this is wrong?" -- no, but most of everything else on that screen is. See updated answer.